Google Admob Ad not showing
I am trying to implement Google Ads into my flutter app. I closely followed the implementation guides but when I start the app even though it says the ad successfully loaded it does not show up. Sometimes it flashes up for a second but immediately disappears afterwords. Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem?
    loadAd() {
    BannerAd banner = BannerAd(
      adUnitId: adUnitId,
      request: AdRequest(),
      size: AdSize.banner,
      listener: BannerAdListener(
          // Called when an ad is successfully received.
          onAdLoaded: (ad) {
        debugPrint('$ad loaded.');
        setState(() {
          _isLoaded = true;
        });
      },
          // Called when an ad request failed.
          onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, err) {
        debugPrint('BannerAd failed to load: $err');
        // Dispose the ad here to free resources.
        ad.dispose();
      }, )
    );
    banner.load();
    setState(() {
      _bannerAd = banner;
    });
  }

 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _isLoaded
        ? Container()
        : Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: SizedBox(
            height: AdSize.banner.height.toDouble(),
            width: AdSize.banner.width.toDouble(),
            child: AdWidget(
              ad: _bannerAd!,
            ),
          ),
        );
  }


You are toggling _isLoaded = true; inside onAdLoaded so inside view as per your condition of _isLoaded there will be only Container, you can replace condition with !_isLoaded

@HitarthChhunchha Oh my god how did I miss that for so long. Thanks a lot!
